# How does Pandas treat the aggregate function sum versus diff

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using python and pandas and I have a data set that looks something like:

```
                            District             Race/Ethnicity      Value 
3   Achievement First Academy District  Black or African American    30.0   
4   Achievement First Academy District  White                         0.0  
10  Amistad Academy District            Black or African American    40.5      
11  Amistad Academy District            White                        23.1
```

So if I want to group by and sort by the sum of each district. I just have to do the following:

```
df= df.groupby('District')
df = abs(df.sum()).sort_values('Value', ascending=False)
```

I get exactly what I want from this:

```
District                                    Value                                                 
Achievement First Academy District           30.0
Amistad Academy District                     63.6
```

But say I want the difference within each district. And I do the following:

```
df= df.groupby('District')
df = abs(df.diff()).sort_values('Value', ascending=False)
```

I get an output completely different than when I did the sum. I get:

```
    Value
4   30.0
10  17.4
```

I really an output like when I used sum. Is there a difference in the way Pandas handles sum and diff? And how would get an output like when I do sum?

Answer (score 0):

`sum` sums *all* the elements into a single number.  `diff` takes the differences (plural) between element and the element before it and returns a sequence of all of them.  You see them as parallel because your groups have only two elements, but in general they're not parallel at all.  Here's a simple example:

```
>>> x = pandas.Series([5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
>>> x.sum()
15
>>> x.diff()
0   NaN
1    -1
2    -1
3    -1
4    -1
dtype: float64
```

If you know that the difference you want is always the the first element minus the second in each group, then you could do this:

```
g = df.groupby('District')
new_df = g.Value.apply(lambda x: x.iloc[1] - x.iloc[0]).sort_values(ascending=False)
```

But if you ever have a school with more than two racial groups, you'll have to rethink what you want to compute, because in that case "the difference" will not be well-defined.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to reorder the original dataframe by the new ordered series?